# $firebaseObject undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

So I have my AngularJs + AngularFire with email/password Authentication working, also have a node called "users" where I can list all the users authenticated to my app, as you can see:
[image]

So, in my authentication service I have an AngularJs factory:

```
.factory('Auth', function($firebaseAuth, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray){

 var ref = firebase.database().ref();
 var auth = $firebaseAuth();
 var users = $firebaseArray(ref.child('users'));
 var firebaseUser = auth.$getAuth();

var Auth = {

getStudent: function(studentId){
  console.log(studentId)
  return $firebaseObject(ref.child('users').child(studentId));
},

studentSignupProfile: function(profile){
    console.log('Student profile service..!');
    var obj = Auth.getStudent(firebaseUser.uid);
    console.log(obj.name);

    return obj.$loaded().then(function(){
      obj.phone = profile.phone;
      obj.address = profile.address;
      return obj.$save();
    });
}

};

return Auth;
});
```

This is my controller:

```
 $scope.studentSignupProfile = function(profile){
    console.log(profile);
    if (profile == undefined) {
        toaster.pop('info','Deseamos saber más acerca de tí!');
    } else {
        Auth.studentSignupProfile(profile).then(function(msg){
            toaster.pop('info','Perfil actualizado!');
            $state.go('home');
        });
    }
}
```

The response is undefined in console.log(obj.name). And as you can see the user UID exist (picture above).

In my getStudent function there is a console.log(studentId) that show me the exact uid => 4BAIdOXZv6NTEKsjgI15JTajFtz2. But when I tried to grab the $firebaseObject it show me undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing to the console before your object has loaded. That `console.log()` should be inside the `$loaded` handler so it will wait before trying to write the name:

```
var obj = Auth.getStudent(firebaseUser.uid);

return obj.$loaded().then(function(){
   // object now loaded
   console.log(obj.name);

  obj.phone = profile.phone;
  obj.address = profile.address;
  return obj.$save();
});
```

Comment: Wow, man to be honest, I feel stupid for this, but thanks! I appreciate your help! XD